# xhr is not defined | mithril js

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, mithril.js

I have recently started experimenting with Mithril js and stumbled upon a basic requirement of sending some Authorization and other headers along with the request. After reading documentation and some examples online I understood that this is how it can be done -

```
m.request({
  method: "GET"
  url: "/some/url/"
  config: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "".concat("Token ", API_TOKEN));
  }
});
```

My question here is where is the xhr being passed? Because this will obviously through error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: xhr is not defined`

I m unable to set headers. If I have to declare **XMLHTTPRequest** instance and use **open()** there then what would be the need of **m.request()**?

What am I doing wrong? Directions would help.

Answer (score 1):

That should work just fine, provided the `config` hook is giving you the `xhr` object as the first parameter. [It is, according to the documentation](http://mithril.js.org/mithril.request.html#configuring-the-underlying-xmlhttprequest)

I did notice some syntax errors however (missing commas). Does this resolve?

```
m.request({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/some/url/", 
  config: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "".concat("Token ", API_TOKEN));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW Those commas were there in the actual code :) Also i found the issue. What I was actually doing was something like this - `config: someXHRFunction(xhr)` When i changed it like the way I put in question - `config: function(xhr){console.log("XHR found" + xhr)}` then it worked. Which is weird.

Comment: @KeshavAgrawal it's not. You need to learn the difference between a call and a declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all you need to do (according to the [Mithril documentation](https://mithril.js.org/request.html)) to set custom headers is this:

```
m.request({
    method: "GET",
    url: "/some/url/",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Token <token_placeholder>",
    },
})
```